# How to run multiple machine learning inference models?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning

Ive a video sample on which I want to run

- gender detection ,
- emotion detection,
- age detection,
- person identification

Ive built for separate models for each one of them and they all are working fine. My question is that

1. How to train a single model to perform all these 4 activities together.
2. If not possible to do it all with a single model, then what shall be the architecture methodology hardware or software wise ?

Comment: Hi, perhaps run them in parallel and store the result?

Comment: Which framework are you using for building the models?